# left speaker doesn't work correctly on an old macbook (Nvidia MCP79)

Tags: sound, mac, macbook-pro, soundcard

My left speaker isn't working on my '09 Macbook Pro with Ubuntu Mate 22.04

Here are the details:

```
$ lspci | grep Aud
00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1)
```

- both channels work with earphones, but not with speakers
- Tested it like this and front left didn't work, but front right came out of the right speaker
  [image]
- switched to 5.1 mode, and rear left and rear right both work, while the others don't. rear right comes out the right speaker and rear left comes out the left speaker
  [image]
- I also installed the same thing on a '13 Macbook Air, and everthing works fine

```
$ lspci | grep Aud # this is the info for my other computer that _does_ work
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

- everything worked with osx a before
- some more info

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
$ uname -r
5.19.0-50-generic
```

these guys were talking about a similar problem like 12 years ago:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/337314

Does anybody have any idea what to do?  Is it a mapping problem that I can fix as a user?

It seems to work if I leave it in 5.1 mode, except I guess as soon as I try to listen to something with different rear and front tracks, it won't sound right?

---

Sorry I should have probably provided this:

```
00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1
    Subsystem: Device 1234:5678
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 80020000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

---

Answer to a question in a comment:
[image]

Comment: Are there any additional drivers available/in use? Check the additional drivers tab in Software & Sources.

Comment: No. The only additional driver is for WiFi. Maybe I need to download one from somewhere?